# Spring MVC Controller Not Found

Tags: java, spring-mvc

This is probably an easy one, but I'm missing something I guess. The problem comes down to this: I am trying to use a HelloController to display "/WEB-INF/hello.jsp". Unfortunately, I get a 404 when trying to access http://example.com/app/hello

Here is the code. Probably an easy fix.

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<display-name>app</display-name>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

 <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>
      org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

applicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="web.controller" />

<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
    p:prefix="/WEB-INF/" p:suffix=".jsp" />

</beans>
```

HelloController.java:

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/hello", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView helloWorld() {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        mv.setViewName("hello");
        return mv;
    }
}
```

hello.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
   <title>Hello</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Hello</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Update: Added error message per request.

> Error 404--Not Found   From RFC 2068 Hypertext Transfer Protocol --
>   HTTP/1.1:
>     10.4.5 404 Not Found
>
> The server has not found anything matching the Request-URI. No
>   indication is given of  whether the condition is temporary or
>   permanent.
>
> If the server does not wish to make this information available to
>   the client, the status code 403 (Forbidden) can be used instead. The
>   410 (Gone) status code SHOULD be used if the server knows, through
>   some internally configurable mechanism, that an old resource is
>   permanently unavailable and has no forwarding address.

Comment: Did you try with `<mvc:annotation-driven />`?

Comment: I'd had it in there before with no luck. I just put it back into applicationContext.xml with no luck.

Comment: On appliation startup did you see somethin like:
`INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/hello/*] onto handler 'helloController'` ?

Comment: @Vacuum: no. I'm trying to get the log4j listener in there to try to get something besides the basic weblogic startup stuff.

Comment: @jason have check your request call is coming to your controller  "/hello" method by system.out.println() function. Beacuse i think the request is coming but dispatcher is not finding a view page i.e. hello.jsp

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This the problem (in `web.xml`):

```
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
```

This will redirect *all* requests to the Spring servlet, *including* your request from the controller to the JSP.  Essentially, the control flow will loop from your controller back into Spring again. You need to narrow that down so that the request for the JSP goes direct to the underlying container, rather than to Spring.

Try changing it to

```
<url-pattern>/app*</url-pattern>
```

And try again.  You might need to fiddle a bit with leading and trailing slahes to make it work (e.g. `<url-pattern>/app*</url-pattern>` or `@RequestMapping("hello")`, etc)

Comment: Still not having any luck. At this point, I'm wondering if Spring is picking up the controller class.

Comment: @Jason: Show us the 404 page. That style of it gives a clue as to what's not found.

Answer (score 1):

Please check that your all controller class/sub-packages or other classes are within the same package as your have mentioned in the following line:

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.kfs" />
```

Comment: <context:component-scan ... /> implies the effects of the 'annotation-config' tag

Answer (score 0):

As you metioned in comment, log dont give you infromation that Controller mapped to specific url. So I think prblem is in controller.

Make sure, controller in the "mil.army.retain.web.controller" package and turn on the annotation-config:

```
<context:annotation-config />
```

Comment: That was another thing I had tried with no luck. And it also seems I forgot to edit my package name...

Comment: The webserver log in the Eclipse console tends to say either nothing or no mapping found for /app/hello.do. I don't have the Log4J listener set up, so I can't monitor the application startup to see the spring initialization yet.

Comment: too bad, please setup logging and tell us whats going on